# Group by 2 columns while sorting sorting by a 3rd

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with 3 columns: A, B and C. I would like to group by A and B and display those sorted by C with python. Is this possible?

Comment: So how do you want to summarize c, since group by lends itself to aggregation? Show your data and describe desired outcome.

Comment: lets say A is gender and B is birth state then C, the age, I want to be in sorted order

Comment: Would you like to use `groupby` or set the index to [A, B] and then sort on C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can  first we can group by A and B column and then can apply the sort for C column this will sort the data frame by C column.

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B'])
df.sort('C', ascending=False)
```